# How To Not Have "=" Changed To 0 From DataFrame.to_excel Using XlsxWriter

Tags: pandas, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

I can't seem to identify why my DataFrame changes a string of "=" to 0.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'rate': ['=', '+', '-']})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_urls': False})
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test', index=False)
writer.save()
```

For some reason, it keeps the "-" and "+" but changes "=" to 0.

Comment: Switching to `engine='openpyxl'` seems to fix the problem.  I think this is an `xlsxwriter` bug, as I can reproduce the behavior exclusively using `xlsxwriter` independent from `pandas`.

Comment: It is not a bug. Just different default behaviour.

Comment: I've also used openpyxl. I much prefer XLSXwriter :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas uses XlsxWriter's `write()` method which by default treats strings beginning with `=` as formulas.

You can change this behaviour by setting `strings_to_formulas` to `False` (in addition to the `strings_to_urls` that you are already using):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Test.xlsx', 
                        engine='xlsxwriter', 
                        options={'strings_to_urls': False, 
                                 'strings_to_formulas': False})
```

See the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#constructor) for more details on XlsxWriter constructor options.

**Note**: the Pandas `options` syntax changed to `engine_kwargs` after version 1.3.0. See the updated [XlsxWriter Pandas docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#passing-xlsxwriter-constructor-options-to-pandas) for the new syntax.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much. I thought it was a formula thing, but didn't know where to look.

Comment: FYI: the `options` keyword argument has been deprecated in pandas 1.3.0 and removed in 2.0.0. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76662159/9681081) for updated syntax

Answer (score 2):

Since pandas 1.3.0, the correct syntax is:

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
    "Text.xlsx",
    engine="xlsxwriter",
    engine_kwargs={"options": {"strings_to_formulas": False}},
)
```